# Iterate over a list of items

Tags: html, testing, telerik, telerik-test-studio

I have a list of items in a selection box like the below:

```
<li id="ShowOption1">Yes</li>
<li id="ShowOption2">No</li>
<li id="ShowOption3">Maybe</li>
<li id="ShowOption4">Not sure</li>
...
```

We then have a separate button which the user presses to see a report based on their selection.

What I want to do is iterate through the list and press the go button.

How do I accomplish this is Test Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Test Studio GUI, I would have the selection process take place in a data-driven test fragment which dynamically identifies the list options based on ID.

I'm assuming you know how to bind values from a datasource.

The data-source would read:

`ElementID, ListText
ShowOption1, Yes
ShowOption2, No
ShowOption3, Maybe
ShowOption4, Not sure`

Your primary test would be:

- Navigate to the target page
- [Test as a step] [Data-Bound] Select Listbox Values
- Click Go

The fragment would be:

- Wait for DynamicListOption is visible
- Select 'ByText' option '$(ListText)' on 'DynamicListOption'

The find logic for DynamicListOption would be:
* tagname is exactly li
* id is exactly $(ElementID)

Summary:

The fragment iterates through a list of element IDs, finds the elements, then selects on option based on text values. Also, adding and removing elements is pretty simple.